# Firebase export to BigQuery event timestamp timezone

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have a Firebase that linked to BigQuery to send events data.
It creates tables in the old partition way where the date is part of the table name.

Firebase creates a schema that has `event_timestamp` and `event_date`.
When I look in a partition of specific date the `event_date` has the same date as the partition but the minimum timestamp starts on 9 pm of the previous date and ends before 9 pm of the partition date.

In the documentation of [Firebase schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) it is written that `event_timestamp` is "The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client."

So what exactly the timezone of the `event_timestamp`, the `event_date` and the date of the partition for Firebase schema?

Is it that the `event_timestamp` is written in local time?

Comment: "The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client."... therefore the timezone must be UTC. Besides it seems to be an epoch time, which by definition should be UTC.

Answer (score 3):

From what i could understand from the documentation, `event_date` and the table name follow the timezone of your firebase project configuration; and `event_timestamp` follows UTC.

> When I look in a partition of specific date the event_date has the same date as the partition but the minimum timestamp starts on 9 pm of the previous date and ends before 9 pm of the partition date.

If you query the table using [TIMESTAMP_MICROS()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros)

```
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as datetime_utc
```

The return will contain the timezone info

```
2021-05-05 14:26:37.704002+00:00
```

So if you need to use local time, instead of using the timestamp as is cast it to the same timezone of your project and you should be fine.